# Why isn't my do while statement working

Tags: c++, while-loop

Can you please fix this program. It will not cout z.

```
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    int x, y, z, a;
    cout << "Please enter a number" << endl;
    cin >> x;
    cout << "Please enter another number" << endl;
    cin >> y;
    cout << "What do you want to do with these numbers?" << endl;
    cout << "1 = +" << endl;
    cout << "2 = -" << endl;
    cout << "3 = *" << endl;
    cout << "4 = /" << endl;
    cin >> a;

    do {
        z = add(x, y);
    } while (a == 1);

    do {
        z = sub(x, y);
    } while (a == 2);

    do {
        z = mul(x, y);
    } while (a == 3);

    do {
        z = dis(x, y);
    } while (a == 4);

    cout << z;
    return 0;
}
```

I tried using the do while statement, but I can not get it to work.
---EDIT---
Added proper indenting, why wont it do so atomatically?

Comment: @PSR Huh? I do not understand. Please provide more details.

Comment: Your loops don't modify `a`. So if it goes into one of the loops, it will never get out.

Comment: can u use switch statement

Comment: @PSR Lokoko suggested the switch statement below, but no, I can not use that.

Comment: and why dont you want to use the switch statement ?

Comment: @Lokoko I will! I promise!

Comment: A few have shown that you have an infinite loop when the user enters 1, but furthermore a do while guarantees the body will execute at least once. So even if the user entered 2, they would get an `add()` and infinitely many `sub()`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whichever option you enter, its going to enter that do-while loop and never exit because the condition will always be satisfied. Ex. if i enter 1 then it will enter :

```
do {
    z = add(x, y);
} while (a == 1);
```

and since a will always be 1 it will never exit this. Same is the case with the other conditions. Instead you could use a switch statement. Something like :

```
switch(a) {
    case 1 : z = add(x, y);
             break;
    case 2 : z = sub(x, y);
             break;
    case 3 : z = mul(x, y);
             break;
    case 4 : z = div(x, y);
             break;
    default : cout<<"Please choose a valid option to proceed.";
}
cout << z;
return 0;
```

Also, you do not use do-while in such cases. Even if you exit the loop, it will always divide(x, y) since do-while is such that it enters and then sub-sequently checks for the condition. You could however use a while loop something like this :

```
while(a==1) {
    z = add(x, y);
    a = -1;
}

while(a==2) {
    z = sub(x, y);
    a = -1;
}

while(a==3) {
    z = mul(x, y);
    a = -1;
}

while(a==4) {
    z = div(x, y);
    a = -1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This switch statement is pretty cool. I will play around with it for a bit. Also, I noticed that you used div(x, y), however, I was unable to use div, I was only allowed to use dis. so in my code, its dis(x, y). What causes this? is div busy or something?

Comment: sry it was a typo :) could you pls. mark the ans. as correct if your issue is resolved ? tnks.

Answer (score 0):

The statement:

```
 while( 1 >= a <= 4)
```

is incorrect [well, it's correct C syntax, but it's most likely not what you wanted, since it does]:

```
while( (1 >= a) <= 4);
```

And since the result of `(1 >= a)` is either `0` or `1`, it is always `<= 4`. You need to do:

```
while ( (1 >= a) && (a <= 4) );
```

[Parenthesis simply for clarity, you can remove the two inner sets of parenthesis]

Answer (score -1):

Your code is entering an infinite loop, modify it like so

```
   int main()
{
using namespace std;
int x, y, z, a;
do
{
cout << "Please enter a number" << endl;
cin >> x;
cout << "Please enter another number" << endl;
cin >> y;
cout << "What do you want to do with these numbers?" << endl;
cout << "1 = +" << endl;
cout << "2 = -" << endl;
cout << "3 = *" << endl;
cout << "4 = /" << endl;
cin >> a;
switch(a)
{
  case 1:
    z = add(x, y);
    break;
  case 2:
    z = sub(x, y);
    break;
  case 3:
    z = mul(x, y);
    break;
  case 4:
    z = dis(x, y);
    break;
}  
cout << z;
} while( 1 >= a <= 4)
return 0;
}
```

modified as per lokoko's suggestion

Comment: You dont need so many if statements. Thats why there is a switch case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It did help me out, but is there any way of using the do while statement if I really wanted to use it?

Comment: If you really want to keep your old code and avoid an infinite loop try this 
do {
    z = add(x, y);
    a = 5;
} while (a == 1);

Comment: I would make that a little prettier.

Comment: @Premsuraj Thank you, I want to learn how to twist the codes.